# Fix regular expression to extract key-value pairs from file names

Tags: regex

I am struggling to fix the following regular expression to extract key-value pairs from file names.
File names are of the format:

`FilePrefix_Key1=<0 or more spaces><optional +, - or none><optional decimal or integer value><0 or more spaces><unit/setting which may contain letters, and math operators e.g., slash>_Key2= ... .ext`

I wrote the following regular expression (https://regexr.com/5lflm)

`(?<=Set= *)([+-]?\d*\.?\d+?) *([A-Za-z-+^/*()]{1}[A-Za-z0-9-+^/*()]*)(?= *_|\.|\s)`

but it fails on the following text as "High" is not returned in the second capture group.

`FilePrefix_Speed= 3.5 kmph_Accel= +0.5 m/(s^2) _Height=+7m_Set=High.txt`

Although it can be captured correctly by changing `([+-]?\d*\.?\d+?)` to `([+-]?\d*\.?\d*?)` but then "Accel" key is not captured properly (only `+0` is returned in the second capture group).

Could you please help me to fix this expression?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, have you had a chance to check [my approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65998540/3832970)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `\d+\.\d*` alternative to the first capturing group that will allow matching one or more digits, a dot and then any zero or more digits:

```js
Accel=\s*([+-]?(?:\d*\.?\d+|\d+\.\d*))\s*((?!\d)[A-Za-z\d+^/*()-]+)(?=\s*[_.\s])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sv2ZPk/1). Note I replaced literal spaces with `\s`, and shrunk the
`_|\.|\s` to `[_.\s]`.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const texts = ['FilePrefix_Speed= 3.5 kmph_Accel= +0.5 m/(s^2) _Height=+7ms_Set=High.txt', 'FilePrefix_Speed= 3.5 kmph_Accel= +0. m/(s^2) _Height=+7ms_Set=High.txt'];
const regex = /Accel=\s*([+-]?(?:\d*\.?\d+|\d+\.\d*))\s*((?!\d)[A-Za-z\d+^/*()-]+)(?=\s*[_.\s])/g;
for (const s of texts) {
  console.log(s, '=>', Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => `Group 1: ${m[1]}, Group 2: ${m[2]}`) );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I accepted your answer because it is very close to what I needed, but the expression had to be amended to Accel=\s*([+-]?\d*\.?\d*)\s*((?!\d)[A-Za-z\d+^/*()-]+)(?=\s*[_.\s]) or else if Accel was changed to Set, "High" was not captured by the second group.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this regex can help:

```
(_[^=]+)=\s*([^_\n]+)(?=_|\.\w{3}$)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/9mMQn2/1/

- `(_[^=]+)` capture key that starts with an underscore, match if not an equal sign
- `=\s*` match equal sign and optional spaces
- `([^_\n]+)` match value, cannot be an underscore or new line
- `(?=_|\.\w{3}$)` positive look-ahead for underscore of next key or file extension

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is quiet general but does not separate number from units, which is my main concern at this point.